# Can't ALTER COLUMN TYPE in PostgreSQL "0A000: Cannot alter column "FIELDA" of relation "TABLEA"

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift, ddl

Trying to run the below script:

```
ALTER TABLE SCHEMA.TABLEA
ALTER COLUMN FIELDA TYPE VARCHAR(5)
```

And I am getting the following error:

> 0A000: Cannot alter column "FIELDA" of relation "TABLE"

The field is currently an integer and contains no data, only nulls.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Redshift

Comment: [According to the manual](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html) you can only change the size of a VARCHAR column with that, not the underlying data type completely.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the AWS documentation you cannot change the data type of a VARCHAR only the size.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_ALTER_TABLE.html